# Unity: How to check if Capsule is fallen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 10 Capsules in my game.

I want to check if those Capsules are standing like they do when the game starts, or if they are fallen down (laying on the ground).

What i would need is:

- Check if the transform.up Vector is 45° different to the normal Vector3.up

But i don't know how to do that?!

Comment: *"or if they are fallen down (laying on the ground)."* Falling down and laying down are not the-same thing.....Which one is it?

Comment: Indeed. I think they meant "fallen over"

Comment: yeah sorry, i meant fallen over, english is not my native language, sorry!!

Comment: See Rzihm's answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `Vector3.Angle(gameObject.transform.up, Vector3.up)`

Compare the output of `Vector3.Angle(gameObject.transform.up, Vector3.up)` to a limit, and see if the angle exceeds (or meets?) that limit.

```
GameObject gameObject; // given
float angleLimit;      // given - measured in degrees
float upAngle = Vector3.Angle(gameObject.transform.up, Vector3.up);
if (upAngle >= angleLimit) {
    // gameObject is not upright
}
```